# Web crawler find the whole html code

Tags: java, html, jsoup, web-crawler

Note that I am using java in eclipse and jsoup library.
My code is:

```
Document doc = null;
        String crawUrl = this.getCrawlUrl();
        doc = Jsoup.connect(crawUrl).get();
        Elements hrefs2=doc.select("html");
        System.out.println(hrefs2);
```

I am trying to get the whole html code of specific page but when there is something like div into div I am not getting it.
How can I get the whole html code from specific page?

Answer (score 0):

You can try-

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(crawUrl).get();

System.out.println(doc.toString());
```